# Laravel 5 Namespace issue fatal error exception

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

Im having this fatal error exception that i cant seem to figure out:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Controller' not found

For some reason im not sure why it is tacking controller at the end of that error. My namespace for the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Announcement;
use App\Http\Requests;

class AnnouncementController extends Controller
{
   ...
}
```

and my routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function () {


    Route::resource('announcements','AnnouncementController');



});
```

But when i navigate to the `/admin/announcements` route i get that fatal exception with the Controller tacked on at the end..

This controller is in the `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` directory so i m not sure why i m getting this error. Am i name spacing wrong?

Comment: You extend Controller. There probably isn't a controller class in `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`

Comment: Ive tried adding the namespace use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; still no luck :/ AndrewL

Comment: Use the full qualified class name

Comment: try to remove this `'namespace'=>'Admin'` and add the `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Comment: you can leave the `'namespace' => 'Admin'` then just refer to the controller in the route as `AnnouncementController`. Laravel assumes `App\Http\Controllers` namespace is what you are starting with, based on your RouteServiceProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function () {

    Route::resource('announcements','Admin\\AnnouncementController');

});
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Announcement;
use App\Http\Requests;

class AnnouncementController extends Controller
{
   ...
}
```

if this dosent work, check if you have a Controller called Controller in `app/Http/Controllers/`

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!! It was missing the controller namespace since i created a new directory for Admin controller i needed to use App\Http\Controllers\Controller. Such a obvious mistake... the struggle lol